# Check if value exists in list's column (Python)

Tags: python, list

Probably this question was already asked (if so, please help me, but I couldn't find). So, my question is:

**How to check if a value exists in list's column**

```
numbers = [
            [5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
            [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
            [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
            [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
            [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9],
        ]
```

I want something like this:

```
if 4 in numbers.columns[2]: # checking if 4 exists in column 2
    print("dang")
```

I know iterating through the list and checking column values one by one, but is there better solution? Or what would be the best solution?

Comment: If this is a list of lists, `if any(row[2] == 4 for row in numbers):` - essentially this is equivalent to iterating (with a `break` when the first match is found)

Comment: Note that lists are made to represent arbitrarily sized collections of arbitrary items – that's not ideal for  regular data structures such as matrices or "list of columns". You might want to use ``numpy`` or a similar library instead.

Comment: Just to reinforce @MisterMiyagi's point here, you are clearly expecting there to be a more efficient solution, and if you use a numpy array then this will fulfil that expectation. Clearly at some level there still has to be an iterative check, but that iteration will happen inside optimised compiled library code, rather than in pure python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly check whether the desired element is in the sequence of "n'th elements of each row":

```py
if 8 in (row[2] for row in numbers):
   print("found")
```

Note that lists are made to represent arbitrarily sized collections of arbitrary items – that's not ideal for regular data structures such as matrices or "list of columns". You might want to use `numpy` or a similar library instead, since it has a concept for multi-dimensional arrays.

```py
import numpy as np

#        v---------------v a regular array of row x column size
matrix = np.array(numbers)

#            v----------v of all (:) rows take the third (2) element
found = 8 in matrix[:, 2]
```

Comment: Nice solution but I think I'd call the loop variable `row`.

Comment: @alani Good point, I keep mixing up the two... :/

Comment: One other correction needed though, you've used different variable names for the array on lines 2 and 3 of your numpy code.

Comment: (Okay, I see this is now corrected.)

Answer (score 2):

perhaps something like

```py
if any(4 == row[2] for row in numbers):
   print('dang')
```

Comment: No, you don't want `in` in this context